# Viewing an uploaded item in DSpace 4.2 xmlui

Tags: xslt, sitemap, dspace, apache-cocoon

This is how the my search results page of DSpace looks like :

[image]
On clicking the item a new page opens up showing its description:

[image]

The description page opens the file upon clicking View/Open. Is it possible to directly open the file upon clicking its title on the results page? I want to skip the item description page.

As per my understanding [this](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/master/dspace-xmlui/src/main/java/org/dspace/app/xmlui/aspect/artifactbrowser/ItemViewer.java) is the `Java` file which is called to render items. Do I need to make changes to this file? Or is it possible to achieve what I want by simply modifying the `sitemap` and `xsl` files?

Comment: What are you thinking to do if there is none or more than one file?

Comment: Currently we're only considering items containing a single file

Comment: I believe you have to edit `item-list.xsl` for browse and `discovery.xsl` for search results. `discover.xsl` by the way is found under the `themes/dri2xhtml-alt/aspect/artifactbrowser`. It will save you time during an upgrade if you'll just copy the relevant templates into `Mirage.xsl`, preferably under the `modules` directory mentioned [here](https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC4x/Advanced+Customisation).

Comment: @euler I commented out lines 183 to 192 in [discovery.xsl](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/master/dspace-xmlui/src/main/webapp/themes/dri2xhtml-alt/aspect/artifactbrowser/discovery.xsl#L183). As a result the action upon clicking the Item name is suppressed. Then I copied lines 505 to 524 from [item-view.xsl](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/master/dspace-xmlui/src/main/webapp/themes/Mirage/lib/xsl/aspect/artifactbrowser/item-view.xsl#L505) after line 182 in `discovery.xsl`. That didn't help. Could you tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: You need to adjust the xpath inside the "view-open" template to apply it on the $metsDoc. There's an example right there in the code you commented out in discovery.xsl.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't help you further with this. I tried what you are trying to achieve and unfortunately I failed in doing so. Like @terrywb suggested, I created a similar logic that generates the thumbnail images, but I can't make the href point to the primary bitstream that is not a thumbnail (eg mets:fileGrp[@USE='CONTENT]). I have **very** limited knowledge about xslt. You can ask in the [DSpace-Tech](http://dspace.2283337.n4.nabble.com/DSpace-Tech-f3276945.html) Mailing list for additional details.

Comment: @euler thanks for all the effort you put in. I'll post my question in DSpace mailing list as you suggested.

Comment: @AntoineSnyers hey it would be nice if you could explain how the xpath is being set, and what's meant by `$metsDoc`

Comment: It's just putting 2 and 2 together, but sure, I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve what I wanted with help from Antoine Snyers, terrywb and [this link](http://sourceforge.net/p/dspace/mailman/message/30499011/). As pointed out by terrywb the information which I needed to read, i.e, the bitstream address of the uploaded file, was stored in the `metsDoc`. Here's a screenshot of my `metsDoc` with the `fileSec` expanded:

[image]

To be able to access the `fileSec` of the `metsDoc` I changed [this line in discovery.xsl](http://10.17.250.230:8080/xmlui/metadata/handle/123456789/3/mets.xml) and [this line in common.xsl](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/master/dspace-xmlui/src/main/webapp/themes/dri2xhtml-alt/aspect/artifactbrowser/common.xsl#L157) to `<xsl:text>?sections=dmdSec,fileSec&amp;fileGrpTypes=ORIGINAL,THUMBNAIL</xsl:text>`.

Then I added/modified the following code to the `itemSummaryList` in `discovery.xsl` so that the title hyperlink now points to the file bitstream.

```
<xsl:variable name="filetype">
    <xsl:value-of select="$metsDoc/mets:METS/mets:fileSec/mets:fileGrp[@USE='CONTENT']"/>
</xsl:variable> 

<xsl:variable name="fileurl">
    <xsl:value-of select="$metsDoc/mets:METS/mets:fileSec/mets:fileGrp[@USE='CONTENT']/mets:file/mets:FLocat[@LOCTYPE='URL']/@xlink:href"/>
</xsl:variable> 


<div class="artifact-title">

            <xsl:element name="a">
                <xsl:attribute name="href">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$metsDoc/mets:METS/mets:dmdSec/mets:mdWrap/mets:xmlData/dim:dim/@withdrawn">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$metsDoc/mets:METS/@OBJEDIT"/>
                        </xsl:when>


            <xsl:when test="$filetype">
                <xsl:value-of select="$fileurl"/>
            </xsl:when>

                    </xsl:choose>

                </xsl:attribute>
```

Similarly, I also made changes to `item-list.xsl` file, and added this line `<xsl:apply-templates select="mets:fileSec/mets:fileGrp[@USE='CONTENT']"
            mode="itemSummaryList-DIM"/>` to the template `itemSummaryList-DIM`.

So finally I got my desired result:
[image]

As visible in the inspector, the `href` attribute of the title now points to the original bitstream of the file :)

Answer (score 3):

The code that generates the thumbnail image is here.

https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/dspace-6_x/dspace-xmlui/src/main/webapp/themes/dri2xhtml/General-Handler.xsl#L34-L47

You could create similar logic to create an href to the original bitstream.

Look at the XML in /metadata/handle/xxx/yyy/mets.xml where xxx/yyy is your item handle.  You should see the information that will point you to the original bitstream.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. But I didn't get *Look at the XML in /metadata/handle/xxx/yyy/mets.xml where xxx/yyy is your item handle*. Could you please explain. Where do I find `/metadata/handle/xxx/yyy/mets.xml `

Comment: according to your screenshot, at http://10.17.250.230:8080/xmlui/metadata/handle/123456789/3/mets.xml

Comment: @AntoineSnyers what I understood is that these [lines](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/master/dspace-xmlui/src/main/webapp/themes/Mirage/lib/xsl/aspect/artifactbrowser/item-view.xsl#L517-L524) of code are used to open the file in view mode. Can these lines be of help?

Answer (score 2):

As was said in the comments, the xsl template to modify is the ["itemSummaryList" in discovery.xsl](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/master/dspace-xmlui/src/main/webapp/themes/dri2xhtml-alt/aspect/artifactbrowser/discovery.xsl#L183)

Replace that href value with `$metsDoc//mets:FLocat[@LOCTYPE='URL']/@xlink:href"`

```
            <xsl:element name="a">
                <xsl:attribute name="href">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$metsDoc//mets:FLocat[@LOCTYPE='URL']/@xlink:href"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="dri:list[@n=(concat($handle, ':dc.title')) and descendant::text()]">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="dri:list[@n=(concat($handle, ':dc.title'))]/dri:item"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <i18n:text>xmlui.dri2xhtml.METS-1.0.no-title</i18n:text>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:element>
```

Comment: I made the change which you suggested, but it didn't work. So I then replaced the href value in the corresponding [line](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/master/dspace-xmlui/src/main/webapp/themes/dri2xhtml-alt/aspect/artifactbrowser/item-list.xsl#L60) in **items-list.xsl** with `"$metsDoc//mets:FLocat[@LOCTYPE='URL']/@xlink:href"`. Now upon clicking the file name, the same page i.e the /xmlui/discover page is getting reloaded. Maybe the link is not getting resolved properly.

Comment: apparently the files **discovery.xsl** and **items-list.xsl** can only access the fileGrp=THUMBNAIL section of the `metsDoc`. I changed this line in [discovery.xsl](http://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/master/dspace-xmlui/src/main/webapp/themes/dri2xhtml-alt/aspect/artifactbrowser/discovery.xsl#L70) to include `fileGrpTypes=ORIGINAL,THUMBNAIL` and also made similar change to this line in [common.xsl](http://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/master/dspace-xmlui/src/main/webapp/themes/dri2xhtml-alt/aspect/artifactbrowser/common.xsl#L157). But it still doesn't read the xpath. Any suggestions?

Comment: that should be right, could you show us the contents of the $metsDoc? (in a pastebin or something)
you can view it [in your browser](http://10.17.250.230:8080/xmlui/handle/123456789/3/mets.xml) or by doing a [copy-of](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_copy-of.asp) and inspecting the HTML of the page.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem :) I'm posting an answer